# Cannot replace source of variable within for loop

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace the "www" in src with "refresh" for a collection of images with class "cover".

```
let testing = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");

for (index = 0; index < testing.length; index++) {
    var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");
    x.src = x.src.replace("www", "refresh");
}
```

Comment: var x = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");  <-- does not make sense.... why are you selecting them all again inside of a loop?

Comment: Removed that line. Still does not work.

Comment: removed it for what?

Comment: I removed it to test your suggestion.

Comment: well it is still a collection, you are not selecting the individual ones....

Comment: Ok, how would I select each of the individual ones?

Comment: Just change to `var x = testing[index]` . That's why you created the loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
let testing = document.querySelectorAll(".cover");

testing.forEach(function(el) {
  el.src = el.src.replace("www", "refresh");
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! So you selected each item in the array by using "forEach"?

Comment: Exactly, what you did in loop is that you get all the `NodeList` array again and again, you though it was single element, but it was array of all matched elements, exactly what was in `testing`. If this is correct, please mark it as correct answer :) Glad to help and have a nice day :)